# How do I force base 10 for a number input?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript supports different number bases. Bases 2, 8, 10 and 16 are easily written as:

```
Number(0b10) //2
Number(0o10) //8
Number(10)   //10
Number(0x10) //16
```

Now I want to enter a 4 digit number from 0000-9999 the problem is that in JavaScript not only `0oXX` is octal, but also numbers with leading 0's (if it can). Is there any way to determine the "real" base 10 original input, **without** using a string input?

Example:

```
Number(010) == Number(0o10) //would be true
```

Answer (score 1):

There is now way to force JS to treat `Number(010)` as decimal.

When you write `010` - it's octal literal. But in strict mode  `0`-prefixed [are not allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal).

```
"use strict" 
010.toString()
//Uncaught SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.

"use strict" 
0o10.toString()
"8"
```

So it seems to me, that you'll have to use text input and parse it to achieve your goal.